# What are the fastest ways to take down Abyss Mage and Fatui shields?

Tags: genshin-impact

Probably the most annoying enemies I've encountered yet in Genshin are Abyss Mages and Fatui Skirmishers. Their shields are often the problem -- it's almost as if when I use elements that counter the element they use, it takes forever to whittle their shields down. This is unlike enemies with Geo shields, where if you use a Geo character, you'll take their shields down in no time.

For instance,  with Hydro shields, it would seem you'd use Electro attacks in order to take it down -- yet the reality is even spamming attacks with Lisa while Oz from Fischl is out merely does minor chip damage, so perhaps I"m not using the the optimal element?

Hopefully, I can get some clarification what elements are optimal to be using against all types of Abyss Mage shields, ala:

- Electro shields
- Hydro shields
- Ice shields
- Fire shields

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this, so I can't give this as an answer, but the mechanics of the elemental shield seems to be you need to deal damage to them by way of elemental reaction. This reaction's damage is calculated by the character's elemental mastery. It is possible that both Lisa and Fischl have low Elemental Mastery and therefore deals low damage to the hydro shield

Comment: @Raestloz Except there are very clear cut elements that have superiority over other elements when eliminating shields. For instance, Water is the best against Pyro Abyss Mages, clearly superior to that of Ice and Electro, even though those elements can also clear pyro shields, regardless or character level of elemental mastery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the most optimal elements to clear both Abyss Mage shields and enemy Elemental shields in general:

| Abyss Mage | Optimal Element |
| --- | --- |
| Hydro | Cryo |
| Cryo | Pyro |
| Pyro | Hydro |

| Fatui | Optimal Element |
| --- | --- |
| Cryo Cicin Mage | Pyro |
| Electro Cicin Mage | Pyro (must kill Cicins to make shield weaker) |
| Pyroslinger | Hydro |
| Geochanter | Geo, Claymores |
| Cryogunner | Pyro |
| Hydrogunner | Electro |
| Electrohammer | Cryo |

Comment: For electro shields, use cryo. Zhongly E skill drains enemy Geo shields and construct health.

Comment: could you add a table for the lectors and herald as well? looks like some of them have a weird weakness, the electro and pyro lectors seem to have two weaknesses according to my 2.6 abyss runs | edit: nevermind, the question is only for abyss mages and fatui

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with this too. [This reddit guide,](https://www.reddit.com/r/Genshin_Impact/comments/j6mn2l/i_got_6_star_abyss_floor_83_100_f2p_on_day_8/) and the resulting discussion, greatly helped me understand the mechanics. Im sure there are innumerable ways to use characters to be effective, so looking at some examples of how people are getting through it may be useful.

[This Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VybhMazI2o) may also be useful in this capacity as an example of how to beat each type of shield.

From [the wiki:](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Abyss_Mages)

> Abyss Mages creates an Elemental Barrier surrounding them, preventing anything from dealing damage to their HP, in order to destroy it quickly, you will need to use an element specifically that creates an elemental reaction.

**Tips:**

> Some enemies like the Pyro slime is immune to Overload Elemental
> Reaction due to the elemental damage it deals, but Elemental Reactions
> happening on an Electro Slime deals devastating damage to them due to
> Overload dealing pyro elemental damage.

> Freezing enemies when Freeze
> Elemental Reaction happens increases physical damage, dealing any
> other elemental damage towards the enemy would only waste the
> opportunity for a hard shattering physical damage bonus.

> When Electro
> Charge Elemental Reaction happens, any enemies nearby that is Wet will
> be dealt Electro damage overtime, if enemies or any other characters
> is standing on a wet or flooded floor, there is a chance that you will
> get yourself electrocuted and you will be inflicted with electro
> damage until the electrocution on the water disappears.

> Some enemies
> are not elemental base, but particular ones are immune to some or
> specific elements, if you don't have a specific element to counter
> this, your only way of dealing with them is using physical damage.

> Every Character that uses a book, or an orb is an elementalist, they
> are more effective in dealing elemental status on enemies and inflict
> or create elemental reactions efficiently.

## Pyro Abyss Mage

**Elemental Weaknesses:**

- Hydro
- Electro

**Elemental Effects:**

- Vaporize: Increased damage, element effect dissipates
- Overload: Explosion Occurs, dealing additional Pyro damage

## Cryo Abyss Mage

**Elemental Weaknesses:**

- Pyro
- Hydro

**Elemental Effects:**

- Melt: Increased damage dealt
- Freeze: Freezes enemy, increased physical damage. Frozen enemies when shattered, deals bonus physical damage

## Hydro Abyss Mage

**Elemental Weaknesses:**

- Cryo
- Electro

**Elemental Effects:**

- Freeze: Freezes enemy, increased physical damage. Frozen enemies when shattered, deals bonus physical damage
- Electro charged: Deals Electro damage overtime for a short duration.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question.  I already know what elements counter other elements -- what isn't explained is which element is most optimal against each specific Abyss Mage.  Try it for yourself -- use a Lisa/Fischl/Razor against a Hydro Abyss Mage and you'll experience an oddly prolonged time to destroy their shield.

Comment: @sayu I've listed the elements that each shield type are weakest to. I've also listed a full guide about what type of characters to use, and even generalized tips about how to counter the mages. I would suggest re-reading the reddit post. Otherwise, I'm not sure what more I can give you beyond the full strategy guide I linked

Comment: The question asks for the fastest way. For example, against Hydro Abyss Mages, a little testing shows that Cryo removes their shield faster than Electro would, even though both can remove the shield.

Comment: @sayu a lot of that is very variable and depends on the characters and their stats, as well as what level they are. If you have two identical characters with the same identical level, stats (incl. elemental effectiveness), and somehow use an attack with the same base damage, then you're right and it's interesting that one of these elements is more effective. However, this is unlikely, and the difference in speed/dmg can most likely be explained by a non-elemental factor

Comment: except it isn't variable on characters and their stats? You can try it on say Floor 8 where you encounter Abyss Mages.  My level 1 Kaeya, no artifacts, a level 1 default weapon, deals more ice shield damage than my Level 70 Razor's E ability with level 60 4*star weapon and a full set of +16 artifacts, against a Hydro Abyss Mage. There is a reason why some characters are solely used, regardless of level, to clear out shields -- their elements is just that more efficient that there is no need to level them.