# Elements to bring down Abyss Lector and Abyss Herald shields

Tags: genshin-impact

This is a follow up to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376605/what-are-the-fastest-ways-to-take-down-abyss-mage-and-fatui-shields)

What elements do the most damage to the pyro and electro Abyss Lector shields, and the Abyss Herald shields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lector / Herald shields are standard "force" shields and thus you can just refer to the usual table [here](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Shields/Enemy)

[image]

Therefore use Hydro for the Pyro shield, Cryo against Hydro and Pyro or Cryo against Electro.

Coincidentally this means that if you know you will face Abyss Herald: Wicked Torrents and Abyss Lector: Violet Lightning at the same time and want to save "space", Cryo is the best option for both shields. That said, many prefer to abuse some Bennet mechanics against the Electro Lector variation.

> To break the Electro shield quickly, there is a strategy of using Bennett with a four-piece set effect of Thundering Fury while in the radius created by Fantastic Voyage. The four-piece effect decreases the cooldown of the user's Elemental Skill by 1 second. Inside the radius and with the four-piece set, Bennett can repeatedly use Passion Overload, which has very fast cooldown and high Gauge application, dealing massive damage in the process. His sixth constellation, Fire Ventures With Me, can also inflict additional damage from Pyro-imbued auto-attacks and further reduce Passion Overload's cooldown

Anyway, you should memorize the above table and just refer to that when in doubt. The only exception to this general rule are the Fatui Skirmishers'shields which use a different table as I pointed [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/390669).